# Bad value blogcatalog for attribute name on element meta: Keyword blogcatalog is not registered

Tags: html, validation

IN HTML5 validator, http://validator.w3.org/

When I tested my page content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>Sports News</title>
  <meta name="blogcatalog" content="9BC8949410"/>
</head>
<body class="home">
  This is content here.
</body>
</html>
```

I found an error in line `<meta name="blogcatalog" content="9BC8949410"/>` .

> Line 9, Column 49: Bad value **blogcatalog** for attribute name on element **meta**: Keyword blogcatalog is not registered.

If anybody has an idea about it? Is there any replacement of this keyword ?

Comment: Is this html5 or XHTML5

Comment: It needs to get validated `doctype` HTML5.

Comment: I don't think you need to define xml namespace then